# Relation through paragraph seems to be exclusive

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I implemented the following scheme:

```
Publication (node) - Mention (paragraphs) - Project (node)
```

*Project* is referenced by Reference Entity from paragraphs type and *Mention* is a paragraphs field (Entity Reference Revision) in *Publication*.

This seems to work fine and relations are shown correctly in publications. To show the reverse relation from a *Project* to *Publication* I use an additional view which has a mandatory relation to *Mention* paragraphs field and a filter using the ID from the URL. This view has a strange problem: Only the relation to the last saved publication is shown.

I'll explain it with an example using 2 publications, *Publication1* and *Publication2*. They both have a relation to *Project1* defined trough *Mention* (paragraphs). Both of them show the relation correctly when editing the publication but visualizing *Project1* only shows one relation, either *Publication1* or *Publication2*. To make it clearer:

```
Publication1 - Mention \
                         Project1
Publication2 - Mention /
```

The view listing the publications which mention this project only shows one relation, either to *Publication1* or *Publication2*. What I noticed is that it's always the last saved publication, but only this and not both. So if I save *Publication1*, *Project1* will show the relation, but not the one to *Publication2*. Saving *Publication2* will then show only this relation from *Project1*, but not the one to *Publication1*.

Comment: Is the view a page or a block with a contextual filter?

Comment: It's a block with a contextual filter.

Comment: Two things: A) The contextual filter will only work on full of "Project 1" B) Check if your view block is cached by a container entity (e.g. a view block inside a paragraph)

Comment: A) I'm not sure what you mean by only work on full of Project 1"? B) I call the view block from a template using drupal_view function of Twig tweak module. But the problem seems to be in the view itself as its preview shows the same reduced result.

Comment: I can imagine that Views gets picky on this one. Having the Projects referenced by a mere field would probably work whereas at the same time the extra Paragraphs layer might break the chain somehow. I'd guess you have to do that manually somehow, with an Entity Field Query at best. Last but not least you could try to bend your view to target/list all paragraphs (Mentions) and maybe get the parent entity (Publication) from there somehow.

Comment: Finally I did it using an Entity Field Query coding a custom block and so all results show up.