# EntityQuery on nodes related by ERR and paragraphs

Tags: 8, entities, database, paragraphs

I have content type Publication which relates to content type Project using paragraphs:

```
Publication [field_mention] -> Mention (paragraphs) [field_project] -> Project
```

Now I want to show all referenced Projects on Article templates. Views doesn't show all relations because of the [complexity of this relationship](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261392/relation-through-paragraph-seems-to-be-exclusive).

I try to do it using EntityQuery with the following code used in a Custom Block Module in the following way:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', 'publication')
    ->condition('field_mention.entity.field_project.target_id', \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node'))
    ->execute();
```

The result is empty (after a long loading so) and logs don't show any error.

Is *field_mention.entity.field_project.target_id* the right way to do it or do I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly naming the target entity type using `:` notation? `condition('field_mention.entity:paragraph.field_project.target_id',...)`

Comment: A query like this (with the "magic" `.entity.` resolver) will not work for Paragraphs, because Paragraphs is an Entity Reference **Revision** field, not a normal Entity Reference field. See [issue 2822359 on d.o](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/2822359)

You can either try the patch provided in the issue, or create the SQL query manually.

Comment: ...or try the core patch, see the link to the issue in the previous comment

Comment: Code in 8.6 is quite different to the one changed by the patch and I can't apply it. Looking at the code it looks like entity types are kept in mind.

Comment: @Hudri: You were right with your first comment: Naming the target entity type using : notation works fine. Seems that I forgot to empty cache or something like that. condition('field_mention.entity:paragraph.field_project.target_id',...) just works fine now. So if you want to convert your comment in answer, I'll approve you. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer versions of Drupal (tested with v8.6.2) can also resolve Paragraphs (Entity Reference Revisions) if you explicitly name the target entity type using dot notation:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', 'publication')
    ->condition('field_mention.entity:paragraph.field_project.target_id', \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node'))
    ->execute();
```

Note the `.entity:paragraph.` instead of `.entity.` in the referenced field condition